# Cant seem to get my SEO friendly URL's to work (htaccess)

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo

I'm pretty new to using htaccess files, and I'm trying to have SEO friendly links. Right now I have it setup so that the `.php` extension is omitted from pages with the following code:

```
# (Fig 1.)

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Then I tried to make it so that there were more SEO friendly links, for example

```
http://www.website.com/view-item?id=5
```

would become:

```
htp://www.website.com/view-item/5
```

However, I tried the following code, completely after Fig 1. and it doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^view-item/([0-9]+)/$ view-item.php?id=$1
```

...it gives me a 404. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: SEO friendly urls is pure snake-oil.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand; can you elaborate?

Comment: if you want to spend your time doing this, that's fine, but don't actully believe it will increases your ranking on google or any other search engine.

Comment: I'm not bothered about it increasing my ranking, I just like the idea, it's cleaner

Comment: its also slower, your call :-)

Comment: Ahh, really? Is it noticeable?

Comment: Of course a descriptive URL is better than an ID number. Ignore these comments saying it is snake-oil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rewrite rule has a small mistake:

```
RewriteRule ^view-item/([0-9]+)/$ view-item.php?id=$1
                               ^ here
```

This will only rewrite urls that have the form of:

```
/view-item/0...9/
```

Notice the ending slash.

If you remove it, it should work:

```
RewriteRule ^view-item/([0-9]+)$ view-item.php?id=$1
```

or:

```
RewriteRule ^view-item/(\d+)$ view-item.php?id=$1
```